# Would sign be lost: zeroing out the low-order bits

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, sign

I have a `Coord` class like this:

```cpp
class Coord
{
public:
    Coord(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t z): mVec{{x, y, z}} {}
    
    int32_t operator[](size_t i) const { assert(i < 3); return mVec[i]; }

private:
    std::array<int32_t, 3> mVec
}
```

Now I use my class:

```cpp
Coord origin(-1, 2, -4);

uint32_t DIM = 1 << 12; // 2 ^ 12

// zero out the low-order bits
Coord originAfter = Coord(origin[0] & ~(DIM - 1),
                          origin[1] & ~(DIM - 1),
                          origin[2] & ~(DIM - 1));
```

Does `originAfter` lose the sign of `origin`?

### UPDATE

The code is available [here](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/091fcf72df72ef113589f4a7189df1cb512b7370/openvdb/tree/InternalNode.h#L855).

Comment: Surely, it would have been quicker to *test* this rather than composing a lengthy question? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo More looking for cause or *why* ...

Comment: Technically your code has undefined behaviour because there is an unsigned to signed overflow, which is UB. In practise the sign bit would be preserved on any platform I know about.

Comment: You are masking out the *lower* bits of a two's complement type, the sign is safe.

Comment: @john I'm seeing this code [here on OpenVDB source](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/091fcf72df72ef113589f4a7189df1cb512b7370/openvdb/tree/InternalNode.h#L855) and I'm confused how it would work :(

Comment: @Bob__ Based on how compiler casts are done, I'm not sure!

Comment: @user3405291 In hexadecimal DIM is `00001000`, DIM-1 is `00000FFF`, ~(DIM-1) is `FFFFF000`. Then the `&` operation preserves all bits that are set in ~(DIM-1) and zeroes all bits that are clear in ~(DIM-1). So the lower 12 bits are zeroed and the upper 20 bits are preserved. Since the sign bit is the highest bit it is preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hexadecimal `DIM` is `00001000`, `DIM-1` is `00000FFF`, and `~(DIM-1)` is `FFFFF000`. Then the `&` operation preserves all bits that are set in `~(DIM-1)` and zeroes all bits that are clear in `~(DIM-1)`. So the lower 12 bits are zeroed and the upper 20 bits are preserved. Since the sign bit is the highest bit it is preserved.

Technically however this is undefined behaviour when used on a negative number. In that case the result of `origin[0] & ~(DIM - 1)` is a large unsigned quantity which overflows when assigned to `mVec[0]` which is a signed quantity. Not really a problem in the real world though.